# python plotting a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a pandas dataframe in Python that looks like this:

```
  Jan 15   Feb 15   March 15   April 15
1   val      val      val       val
2   val      val      val       val 
3   val      val      val       nan
4   val      nan      val       nan
5   val      nan      nan       nan
```

I want to plot a graph as follows. The X axis is the months (`Jan 15 | Feb 15 | March 15 | April 15`), and the bars are like so:

```
Jan 15: 5
Feb 15: 3
March 15: 4
April 15: 2
```

^ this is the count of non-null values for each month.

Any help on how to plot it with matplotlib or anything else?

**EDIT**: the values in the df are tuples like so: `(val1, val2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) with [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.count().plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

Solution with [`Series.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.count().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: is there a wat to make a tag cloud of it? for example, instead of a graph, plot in a tag cloud the months, and the largest font moth would be the one with the most data?

Comment: Hmmm, in pandas it is not possible, I am not sure if in matplotlib. I found [this solution](http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.sk/2012/11/a-wordcloud-in-python.html), try it.

Answer (score 2):

This will return a series with the data you want to plot:

```
df.count()
```

This will plot it:

```
df.count().plot.bar();  # the semicolon will suppress output in Jupyter
```

**Edit**: made it a bar chart.

Comment: how do I plot the graph? it prints: `<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x20e3fbc8ef0>`

Comment: I assume you're in Jupyter. You have to enable inline charts by running `%matplotlib inline` once.

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. Then after df.count().plot(), add `plt.show()`. If you're using jupyter notebook you can also use the magic `%matplotlib inline`.
@IanS: add `kind='bar'` in your plot call

Comment: `df.count().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)` is an alternative syntax. The stacked argument is worth knowing about too.

Comment: @JulienMarrec: In what environments do you need `plt.show()`?

Comment: As far as I know, literally anywhere else than jupyter notebook with `matplotlib inline`. I made a habit of always including it. It also mutes down the classic output of a collection of axes when you plot without capturing the axes

Comment: Except Spyder (the IDE). In Jupyter you suppress the output by adding a semicolon at the end. I'll be more careful with my assumptions next time. Thanks!